# Global GIT Ignore: Not pulling

Tags: git, global, gitignore

Applied:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Tried removing the $HOME variable:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.config/git/ignore
```

Can't get it to apply to my plethora of local projects. Much as I love seeing my .sass-cache folder appear on every project, really like to hide this folder from GIT...

Wish one could do a simple `which -a gitignore` to find which one is being used. Would be marvelous.

Thanks ahead of time for any leads.

Comment: What does your `.gitignore_global` file look like?  What is the output of `git config --get-all core.excludesfile`?

Comment: Grabbed the recommended .gitignore file from github. But added this to it:

`.ssas-cache   .ssas-cache/*`

Did not know about the `git config --get-all core.excludesfile` command. Writes `/Users/josh/.config/git/ignore`

Comment: That's the file that should be used for your ignores.  If it's not working, then something is likely wrong with your ignores file (a rule is misspelled, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used: `git config --get-all core.excludesfile`

Edited file presented. Works. Thanks to @jszakmeister